# Excel EDATE Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm using Excel 2013. I have an edate formula in column B which looks at at the date in column A then adds 5 months onto it. My question is, if there is a blank cell in column A a weird date appears in the cell adjacent in column B, is there a way to stop this happening and maybe show nothing in without removing the formula from the column?

[image: ScreenShot of excel]

Comment: If the answer was helpful please mark it as "solved"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to use an IF statement

```
=IF(A2<>"",EDATE(A2,5),"")
```

Copy this down for every cell so it will perform this calcuation on all rows.

The syntax is

```
IF(condition, if condition is true, if condition is false)
```

In this case, the condition is `A2 <> ""` which means A2 is not empty. If it is not empty, move to the true condition (your original formula), else, move to the false condition.

[More detail](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2?CorrelationId=bd0bf35c-8ca8-45b0-9daf-f684ce5bbcbf)

**Edit**

As per comments, if you need to add days to this formula, use

```
=IF(A4<>"",EDATE(A4+14,5),"")
```

Comment: your formula works perfectly, on another column i want to add 14 days onto it so i modified your formula (below) but i get an error message...i think the + symbol is causing the error?    =IF(A4<>"",EDATE(A4+14),"")

Comment: Use `=IF(A4<>"",EDATE(A4+14,5),"")`

Answer (score 1):

First check if there is data on the cell and if it's true then calculate with EDATE:

```
=IF(A4<>"",EDATE(A4,5),"")
```